# Не отрабатывает сервлет до вызова index.jsp страницы

Tags: java, servlet

изучаю работу сервлетов.

есть сервлет:

```
@WebServlet(name = "StudentController", urlPatterns = "/")
public class StudentController extends HttpServlet {

  private StudentModel studentModel = new StudentModel();

  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Student student = studentModel.setStudent("Sergei", 22);

    req.setAttribute("Student", student);
// Если forward настроен на index.jsp то студент пустой
    req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(req, res);

// Если forward настроен на test.jsp то получаю студента
//  req.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/test.jsp").forward(req, res);
    }
}
```

и view index.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Student page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Hi it's a index students page!</h3>
    <jsp:useBean id="Student" class="entities.Student" scope="request" />
    <p>Student name: <jsp:getProperty name="Student" property="name" /></p>
    <p>Student age: <jsp:getProperty name="Student" property="age" /></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

У сервлета стоит urlPatterns на "/" вроде как он должен вызываться по адресу http://server/ а открывается index.jsp с пустыми полями студента.
Поясните мне механизм как при первом запуске index.jsp может получить данные от бина?

Comment: ну так вам нужно вызвать `GET` метод контроллера `StudentController` для того, чтобы получать данные о студенте. Сам по себе этот метод не вызывается. Добавьте какую-то кнопку которая будет делать `request` к контроллеру и уже возвращать данные в ответе.

Comment: Ну давайте представим что это блог где на главную загружаются посты из бд. Никто же не нажимает кнопочку скачать посты. Как правило роутер перенаправляет запрос в контроллер и дальше происходит рендер. Или сервлеты это для других целей?

Comment: Возможно до контроллера не доходит запрос, обычно в по индексу стоит редирект на другой сеовлет.

Comment: А как узнать об этом? Мапинг я сделал, в настройке томката у варника путь / собственно он по нему и отдает  index.jsp

Comment: Нет томкэту это до лампочки он не понимает такой путь.

Comment: ну тогда сделайте этот сервел как `index` для первого перехода на ваш "блог" и чтобы метод `GET` обрабатывался при первом заходе юзера на сайт. `name = "/"` или в ваш `home` сервлет, добавьте обработку юзера.

Comment: @WebServlet(name = "StudentController", urlPatterns = "/") а это разве не оно я же указал urlPattern

Comment: Из того что я понял на данный момент, путь "/" ведет к index.jsp. Если в аннотации задать name то оно и будет последующим параметром URL. Если при этом задать urlPattern = "/" то это корень от server/ServletName. Если urlPattern = "/test" то сервлет отработает по пути server/test. Как настроить отработку сервлета по пути server остается загадкой.